# Loop through multiple files in temp directory and insert files into MS SQL database with existing rows/id's

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-ajax

I have a SQL database with existing rows and attachment ID's. I have a folder of several thousand PDF files that need to be inserted into this database. The files should be inserted in each row based on filename/column. 
Example. One file is called 123.pdf that should be inserted in the row with the ID of 123.
I have created an Asp.net web forms application using the Ajax File Upload tool. It works fine if I use a real directory. How can I do this with a temporary Directory?

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = e.FileName;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            string contenttype = String.Empty;
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".pdf":
                    contenttype = "application/pdf";
                    break;
            }
            if (contenttype != String.Empty)
            {

                string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
                AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(tempPath);
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(tempPath))
                {

                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        //How do I create a temp directory of the files in the AjaxFileUploader?
                    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(CreateTempDirectoryHere);
                    FileInfo[] pdfFiles = dir.GetFiles();
                    foreach (FileInfo pdfFile in pdfFiles)
                    {
                        var attachmentID = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdfFile.ToString());

                        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))

                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spUploadContentBulk", con);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttachmentID", attachmentID);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                            {
                                ParameterName = "@FileName",
                                Value = filename
                            });
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                            {
                                ParameterName = "@FileContent",
                                Value = bytes
                            });
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                            {
                                ParameterName = "@FileType",
                                Value = contenttype
                            });

                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                File.Delete(tempPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            txtError.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand - you actually have all of the information about the file *and* the binary contents of the file in `e`. Why not put *that* into the database; why do you need to go to disk where the temp file has been stored?

Comment: If you want to parse through a folder full of files, and put the contents into a db, I wouldn't use the `FileUpload` tool, just create a constant with the path where the files live, and enumerate the contents there.

Comment: @Jonathan I would like the user to be able to drag and drop the files they would like to upload instead of having to create a folder with only the files to be uploaded. Trying to keep it as simple as possible for the user. Also, if the folder has several thousand files, I may limit their upload to 20 at a time.

Comment: So I think my first point stands: doesn't `e` contain the contents of the file, or at least give you access to the file contents via `e.GetContents()` or something? Instead of trying to go to disk and read from there, can't you read from the event arguments of the upload?

Comment: @Jonathan so how would I access `e.GetContents()`? something like this: `FileInfo[] pdfFiles = e.GetContents()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean something more like this (don't even use a temp folder):

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = e.FileName;
        var bytes = e.GetContents();
        var attachmentID = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        string contenttype = String.Empty;
        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".pdf":
                contenttype = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }
        if (contenttype != String.Empty)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spUploadContentBulk", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttachmentID", attachmentID);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@FileName",
                    Value = filename
                });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@FileContent",
                    Value = bytes
                });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@FileType",
                    Value = contenttype
                });

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        txtError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}
```